# Button Highlight in Xcode

Tags: swift, uibutton

I'm trying to display a second button image when the button is tapped. The second image is displaying but the button gets highlighted and it doesn't look very good. How do I get it to show the second image without highlighting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
button.setBackgroundImage(IMAGE, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```